# How to write a define wrapper around the require js function

Tags: highcharts, requirejs, durandal

I want to wrap the following code as a define method

```
        require([
            'highcharts',
            'highcharts/modules/exporting',
            'highcharts/modules/accessibility'
        ], function (Highcharts) {
            // This function runs when the above files have been loaded.

            // Create a test chart.
            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                series: [{
                    data: [1,2,3,4,5]
                }]
            });
        });
```

I use durandal SPA . so i need to have a define method to cal it from other places .

Comment: You have used the Highcharts tag meanwhile it seems that your requirement is related to general using the RequireJS. Have you already checked the official API of the RequireJS? https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to replace `require` with `define`:

```js
        define([
            'highcharts',
            'highcharts/modules/exporting',
            'highcharts/modules/accessibility'
        ], function (Highcharts) {
            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                series: [{
                    data: [1,2,3,4,5]
                }]
            });
        });
```